# Radiobuttons set attribute checked is not working in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this not working with JQuery?
The property wont be checked to true so or with asnyc function... I tried everything, but it only will working if i set the attribute `checked true` in browser at console. Not even with outsourced async callback functions.

```
for (var i = 0; i < user.benutzer.length; i++)
                {
                    var user_var = user.benutzer[i].benutzer;
                    user_rep = user_var.replace(/ /g, '_');
                    $('#div_buttongroup').append('<label for="' + user_rep + '" class="btn btn-primary" id="label_'+user_rep+'"><input type="radio" class="user_radio" id="' + user_rep + '" value="' + user_var + '" name="radio" autocomplete="off"></input>' + user_var + '</label>');
                    if (i === 0)
                    {
                        t = user_rep;
                       $('#label_'+user_rep).addClass("btn btn-primary active");
                        $('#'+user_rep).prop("checked",true);
                    }       
            }
```

Comment: Well according to your above code, `user.benutzer` is undefined. Please ensure you are providing a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), specifically the 'complete' part :)

Comment: The Model is right...Its a normal JSON array...

Comment: What is your Jquery version?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.4

Comment: make sure in your debugging this is actually catching something $('#'+user_rep)

Comment: I updated now to JQuery-3.2.1, but it has no effect.

Comment: Perhaps anybody knows a workaround?

Comment: I think it was a JQuery bug in combination with radiobuttons. I used a selectbox and everything was working

Answer (score 1):

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

```
$('#'+user_rep).attr("checked");
```

Comment: And .attr is deprecated too

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a JQuery bug in combination with radiobuttons. I used a selectbox and everything was working